Starting application with I/O redirection via *.desktop file
I start music or video with right click and "open with" in Thunar (Xfce). For every entry, there is a *.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications or /usr/share/applications. I want to start an application with a pipe and save the output in a file.
This works in terminal:
mpv file.mp4 > log 2>&1

But that doesn't work when I add the same line to the desktop file:
Exec=mpv file.mp4 > log 2>&1

The file is started, but there is no output. How can I do this? Is there something special when using desktop files? also starting with terminal=true, but that didn't work.

Try Exec=sh -c "mpv file.mp4 > log 2>&1"

@ G-Man Thats it, thanks.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' surprisingly this doesn't seem to have been answered before (at least, I couldn't find a convincing duplicate) - please consider turning your comment into an answer

Apparently Thunar (or whatever tool parses the desktop files)
doesn’t understand shell syntax like > and 2>&1. 
So the standard solution is
to explicitly invoke a shell to handle the command,
like this:
Exec=sh -c "mpv file.mp4 > log 2>&1"

